# Exact amount of comparisions in Insertion Sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I want to get number of permutations of {1, ..., n} for which Insertion Sort does exactly n(n-1)/2 comparisions.
For example, for {1, 2, 3, 4} we got (4, 3, 2, 1), (3, 4, 2, 1), (4, 2, 3, 1) etc. - for all of them InsertionSort does 4*3/2 = 6 comparisions.
Anybody know some exact formula for that?
I am thinking about something like (n-1) + 1 = n, where
1 stands for reverse sequence and then we can swap all of (n-1) pairs in reverse sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint.  The complete list for `(1, 2, 3, 4)` are:

```
(4, 3, 2, 1)
(3, 4, 2, 1)
(4, 2, 3, 1)
(2, 4, 3, 1)
(4, 3, 1, 2)
(3, 4, 1, 2)
(4, 1, 3, 2)
(1, 4, 3, 2)
```

Look at it from last column to first.

Walk step by step through the insertion sorts.  See where they merge.  Do you see a pattern there?

Reversing it, can you figure out how I generated this list?  Can you prove that the list is complete?

The why is what matters here.  Just saying `2n-1` is useless.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but can you give a bit bigger hint? I see that in last column you could only put 1 or 2, in previous 1 or 2 or 3 and in 1st and 2nd column there can be all values, but why is so?

Answer (score 0):

`n(n-1)/2` is the sum of all elements in the range `(1, n - 1)`. Since your sequence has length `n`, you can expand that range to `(0, n - 1)`.

The number of swaps for each insertion would be:

```
run #  list       value    swaps
1      []         a        0 (no swaps possible)
2      [a]        b        1
3      [b, a]     c        2
...
10     [i,...,a]  j        9
...
n      [...]      ?        n - 1
```

So we need to move every element through the entire list in order to achieve the required count of swaps. The number of comparisons can be at most one higher than the number of swaps, which means each value that is being inserted must either be placed at the first or second index of the resulting list. Or

Put differently, assuming ascending ordering of the output:
The input list should in general be a nearly descending list, where each element in the list may be preceded by at most one element that is not larger than the element in question.